# Update / Get user photo from Microsoft Graph API gives "UnknownError" result

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm having trouble updating and getting user's profile photos using the Microsoft Graph API.

For example, sending a PATCH request to  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/[userId]/photo/$value, including correct Authorization and Content-Type headers, with the image binary data in the request body, results in an error response with the code "UnknownError" and an empty message.

Getting user photos results in the same error.

Is there a way to get a more detailed error message? Any ideas on what could be the cause of the error? Are there any known issues with getting/updating photos with the API?

The users for which I'm trying to get/update photos for exist only in an Azure AD. They do not have an Exchange online mailbox. Is that a requirement for using get get/update photo queries in Microsoft Graph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue. Currently, the API only serves photos for users with Exchange online mailbox. We are working on supporting the API for AAD only users as well. Let us know the impact this has on your work and it would help us prioritize it better.

The feedback on returning more meaningful is noted. It would be great if you can share request-id and timestamp present in body of the error response.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've set up an Azure AD for development purposes from which I want to retreive user data. I do not, however, have an Exchange Online subscription for development, as I'd rather not sign up for a new subsciption for that sake.

Here's a fresh example of an error response:
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "d0ff6b9b-20e9-4b45-843f-e1735e0e33da",
            "date": "2016-03-02T12:18:03"
        }
    }
}

Comment: Same issue here. A fix would be highly appreciated.

Comment: We are using AAD as a lightweight identity provider and avatar support in the Graph API would be very useful.

Comment: why is this still an issue more than a year later? it's a shame that such an important project has so many issues with documentation and functionality. These "Unknown errors" generate all sorts of response codes, and sometimes even result in 30 seconds long gateway timeouts.

Comment: why is this still an issue more than a year later?

Comment: Would appreciate an update here too. We are simply trying to display the associate photo for our AD user. This is an External user who wouldn't have an exchange account under our AD.